# Замена верхнего регистра нижним

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача:

Вставьте символа нижнего подчеркивания перед заглавной буквой следующего слова. Если первая буква написана с большой буквы, преобразуйте ее в нижний регистр и не забудьте вставить перед ней символ подчеркивания.

Мой код, который пишет "_" перед заглавной буквой:

```
import re
def snake_case(text):
    return(re.sub(r"([A-Z])", "_\\1", text))
text = input()
print(snake_case(text))
```

Я не знаю, куда мне вставить lower(). Пробовала в print, но какая-то ерунда получается...

P.S.
Цикл For не хочу. Хочу через регулярки)))

Comment: у вас не реализовано даже это "нижнего подчеркивания перед заглавной буквой следующего слова". Обратите внимание на последние два слова

Comment: Ну я проверяла, работает... А как надо, подскажите, пожалуйста?!))) Я только-только начала внедрять рег.выражения.

Comment: У вас будет вставлено подчёркивание перед заглавной буквой в любом месте. Введите слово только из заглавных букв и посмотрите.

Comment: @GrAnd , бэлин((( Мне не надо, чтоб перед первой буквой был "_"(((  Надо  добавить ```[^\S]```  ?!

Comment: Добавьте `\b` в начало регулярки, тогда будет вставлять только перед первой буквой каждого слова. И к сведению: `[^\S]` - это просто `\s`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно с помощью `lambda` такое делать:

```
return(re.sub(r"([A-Z])", lambda m: '_' + m.group(0).lower(), text))
```

В других языках вообще есть для этого специальные `escape`-последовательности в регулярках, но в питоне это не работает или я просто не знаю как туда `\L` применить.

Comment: Спасибо))) Правда я ещё не проходила lambda. Не знаю, что это такое. Сейчас буду искать-читать...

Answer (score 0):

@GrAnd , крч, я не поняла про \b, но 2 дня потратила на то, чтоб написать вот это. Не знаю как, но оно работает и мне засчитали задачу:

```
import re  
def snake_case(text):
    string = re.sub(r'(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', text)
    return(re.sub(r'([a-z])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', string).lower() )    
text = input()
print(snake_case(text))
```